# Initializing generic variable using protocol initializer

Tags: ios, swift, generics, initialization, realm

I have this method, where I would like to initialize a new Realm object(see for-loop else closure) using protocol initializer, but for some reason it doesn't get recognized. I was able to initialize object using default initializer and then update the content, though. Can this be done?

Protocol:

```
protocol UnequallyPersistable: class {

    var uniqueID: String { get set }
    var isDeleted: Bool { get set }

    init(withData data: NSDictionary)
    func update(withData data: NSDictionary)

}
```

Working, but is not optimal:

```
fileprivate func update<Element: UnequallyPersistable>(withData data: Any?, type: Element.Type) where Element: Object {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    realm.beginWrite()

    guard let items = data as? [NSDictionary] else {
        return
    }

    for itemData in items {
        guard let uniqueID = itemData["id"] as? String else {
            continue
        }
        let object = realm.object(ofType: type.self, forPrimaryKey: uniqueID)
        if let _object = object {
            _object.update(withData: itemData)
        } else {
            let newObject = type.init()
            newObject.update(withData: itemData)
            realm.add(newObject)
        }
    }

    try? realm.commitWrite()
}
```

Does not work:

```
fileprivate func update<Element: UnequallyPersistable>(withData data: Any?, type: Element.Type) where Element: Object {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    realm.beginWrite()

    guard let items = data as? [NSDictionary] else {
        return
    }

    for itemData in items {
        guard let uniqueID = itemData["id"] as? String else {
            continue
        }
        let object = realm.object(ofType: type.self, forPrimaryKey: uniqueID)
        if let _object = object {
            _object.update(withData: itemData)
        } else {
            let newObject = type.init(withData: itemData)
            realm.add(newObject)
        }
    }

    try? realm.commitWrite()
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `NSDictionary` in Swift?

Comment: Mainly because Swift dictionary doesn't have `valueForKeyPath` method.

Comment: You could most probably get around that (but it's hard to tell for sure without seeing the actual usage) and get the type safety provided by Swift Dictionaries. Btw, your code compiles fine for me, so if you don't get a compile-time error, please include the code used that produces the runtime error. Moreover, I don't see any reason for declaring `data` as `Any` if you are returning without doing anything if `data` is not an `NSDictionary`, so why don't you change it to be of type `NSDictionary`?

Comment: Noted. I've updated the question with function that does not compile. Actually handling API data is the only place I still use NSDictionary, I just find it more convenient. Regarding the samples, I removed some functionality from above methods before posting to make them more clear, didn't notice that parameters makes no sense anymore, sorry about that.

Comment: Well, I don't really see how is the second, non-working version better than the first one, since if the object actually exists, you just end up recursively calling the update method the same way as you do in the "non-optimal" solution. Moreover, could you please explain why do you need these methods instead of just using `Object.init(value:Any)`, which accepts a `Dictionary` containing key-value pairs for property names and values and then calling `Realm.add(object:Object,update:Bool)`?

Comment: It would be better, because my objects has primary keys(UnequallyPersistable as protocol says). I would prefer to assign my primary key inside initializer, not in update method meant to be called whenever object needs updating. There are multiple reasons why I'm not using those functions, but I don't see how discussing this is related to my original question.